# DEVMODE structure doesn’t have color property for a color printing capable printer

Tags: delphi, printing, vcl

I am working in a label printing Delphi application, and I allow the user to change the printer properties like papersize, orientation, etc.
This works well and there aren't any problems when I change for instance the paper size like this:

```
if ((pdm^.dmFields and DM_PAPERSIZE) = DM_PAPERSIZE) then
    begin
        begin
          pdm^.dmPaperSize := // A device specific value like 270, 275 etc.
          pdm^.dmFields := pdm^.dmFields or DM_PAPERSIZE;
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

That works just right.

But if I try to change the color, the if is never entered

```
if ((pdm^.dmFields and DM_COLOR) = DM_COLOR) then
begin
  pdm^.dmColor := DMCOLOR_COLOR;

end;
```

If I use the next code without the if dmColor does change

```
pdm^.dmColor := DMCOLOR_COLOR;
```

But then, I Couldn’t tell if the user's printer supports color printing or not.

when using :

```
SupportedColor : DWORD;
```

`SupportedColor := DeviceCapabilities(PChar(PrinterName), nil, DC_COLORDEVICE, nil, nil);`

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-devicecapabilitiesa) states, it is supposed to return 1 if the printer supports color printing or 0 otherwise, but it always returns 0 and the printer I am running tests on supports monochrome and black/red printing.

Any ideas why the if statement for the color property is never entered even though the printer supports color?

How else could I know whether the printer supports color or not?

Edit: I added the whole procedure I use.

```
Procedure TEtiquetas.AjustarImpresora();
var
 ADevice : array[0..250] of char;
 ADriver : array[0..250] of char;
 APort   : array[0..250] of char;
 hDm :  THandle;
  dm :  DEVMODE;
 Pdm : ^DEVMODE;
 I : integer;
begin
  Printer.GetPrinter(ADevice, ADriver, APort, hDm);
  Pdm := GlobalLock (hDm);
    if ((pdm^.dmFields and DM_PAPERSIZE) = DM_PAPERSIZE) then
    begin
      pdm^.dmPaperSize := //my paper size (275, 271, etc);

    end;

    if ((pdm^.dmFields and DM_PAPERLENGTH) = DM_PAPERLENGTH) then
    begin
      pdm^.dmPaperLength :=//998,620, etc, in tenths of mm

    end;

    if ((pdm^.dmFields and DM_PAPERWIDTH) = DM_PAPERWIDTH) then
    begin
      pdm^.dmPaperWidth :=//998,620, etc, in tenths of mm

    end;

    {set orientation}
    if  ((pdm^.dmFields and DM_ORIENTATION) = DM_ORIENTATION) then
    begin
      pdm^.dmOrientation := DMORIENT_PORTRAIT;

    end;

    if ((pdm^.dmFields and DM_COLOR) = DM_COLOR) then
    begin
      pdm^.dmColor := DMCOLOR_COLOR;

    end;

  GlobalUnlock(hDm);
  printer.SetPrinter(ADevice, ADriver, APort, hDm);

end;
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Comment: "*[DeviceCapabilities] is supposed to return 1 if the printer supports color printing or 0 otherwise, but it always returns 0*" - then clearly the printer does not actually support color printing, the way you are thinking of. Also, you didn't provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are allocating and using the `pdm` exactly.

Comment: in your first example, `pdm^.dmFields := pdm^.dmFields or DM_PAPERSIZE`is pointless.  You just tested dmFields contains DM_PAPERSIZE, no need to set it.

Comment: Hello @RemyLebeau, I edited my question and added the procedure. If I go to the printer configuration dialog in the windows configurations, it allows me to change between monochrome and black/red. is that a different property, other than color?

Comment: Hello @KenBourassa, I am using `pdm^.dmFields := pdm^.dmFields or DM_PAPERSIZE` to check whether the structure contains the specified property. and it may be not necessary in this case because all printers should have paper size property, but I use it also to check whether the structure has more specific properties like the color.

Comment: @Hiram What your code does is "If 2nd bit = 1 then set 2nd bit to 1". You already know the 2nd bit = 1, no need to "set it more".

Comment: *"... why the if statement for the color property is never entered ..."* - Probably because that's not a color printer, black/red printing is not color printing. I suspect you have to consult to the provider of the printer, they might have some interface that communicates with the driver.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Well, I'll see what I can do, thanks for answering.

Comment: ahh, now I see what you mean @KenBourassa. I removed the code you mentioned. thanks.